# Why is $\lim_{x\to \infty} (-53)^{1/x}$ undefined, while $(-53)^{1/\infty} = 1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why $$\lim_{x\to \infty} (-53)^{1/x}$$ is undefined whereas on the other hand $(-53)^{1/\infty}$ is defined and it's value is $1$. In both Desmos and Wolfram Alpha the value of $(-53)^{1/\infty}$ is $1$. Whereas on the other hand when I checked the value of $$\lim_{x\to \infty} (-53)^{1/x}$$ on Wolfram Alpha, the result given by Wolfram Alpha was undefined. Can anyone solve this discrepancy for me.

Comment: How do you define $(-53)^y$ for real $y?$ WA may be taking $1/x$ as a complex value approaching $0,$ rather than a real value $1/x$ approaching $0.$

Comment: In any event, $x^n$ is, in general, a single valued function when $n$ is an integer. When $n$ is irrational, $x^n$ has infinitely many possible values.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha may be interpreting $1/\infty$ as $0$ and $(-53)^0 = 1$.

Comment: Yes you are correct @HiMatt.

Comment: But why complex value will exist?@ThomasAndrews. Can you define me what is the difference between-$ \to $ $\infty$ and $\infty$

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number, but a symbol that represents a phenomenon. Arithmetic expressions involving $\infty$, such as $1/\infty$, are not defined. Treating $\infty$ like a number will only cause confusion and lead to incorrect mathematical understanding.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}(-53)^{1/x}$ is evaluated by *approaching*. Try for the first few values of $x$ as it explodes, and you end up with alternating complex numbers and negative real numbers, such as:
$$(-53)^{1/2}=\sqrt{-53}=i\sqrt{53}$$
$$(-53)^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]{-53}=-\sqrt[3]{53}$$
$$\vdots$$
Clearly this approaches $0$, but I assume the alternation between real and complex numbers throws off the calculator.

There's a difference between $\lim_{x\to \infty}(-53)^{1/x}$ and $(-53)^{\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}{1/x}}$, and some calculators might use different methods to arrive to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Desmos (I only use it for simple graphing) and Wolfram Alpha to comment on how they handle this.

Assume we are only talking about real values here.

First, $(-53)^{1/\infty}$ is undefined off the bat because $\infty$ is not a real number.

Next, the original expression $lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (-53)^{1/x}$ is undefined because the underlying function is undefined at many values $x>0$ e.g. at even integers. Or for $x>>0$ if you want to focus on large $x$.

An expression that would have a limit would be a sequence such as this:

$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (-53)^{1/(2n+1)}$, which approaches $-1$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

and obviously with any negative integer $m$ replacing $-53$. Note that this does not naively approach $1$ even though $\frac1{2n+1}$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (-53)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left((-1)^\frac{1}{x} \times 53^\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} (-1)^\frac{1}{x} \times \lim_{x \to \infty} 53^\frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} (-1)^\frac{1}{x} \times 1$

That is to say, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (-53)^{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} (-1)^\frac{1}{x}$

$f(x) = (-1)^\frac{1}{x}$ is a weird "function".

$x = 0$, $f(x) =$ undefined(???)
$x = 1$, $f(x) = -1$
$x = 2$, $f(x) = \sqrt {- 1} = i$
$x = 3$, $f(x) = -1$
$x = 4$, $f(x) = \sqrt {i}$
$x = 5$, $f(x) = -1$
$x = 6$, $f(x) = \sqrt [3]i$

As you can see, the function is defined (has a real solution) only when $x \in$ odd numbers. We could then say, I suppose, that ...

$(-53)^{\frac{1}{x}} = -1$, x is *not* even

Hence, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (-53)^{\frac{1}{x}} = -1$